# Eigenfunctions of high order fractional operator

Tags: spectral-theory, fractional-calculus

Is there an explicit formula for the eigenfunctions of the fractional laplacian $(-\Delta)^s$ in a ball when $1<s<2$? I can only found reference when $s\in(0,1)$.